# Publishing a message in an interrupt

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I don't want to publish messages in while(ros::ok) loop, but rather when an interrupt is called. How can I do that?
I'm completely new to ROS, so please try to answer, so that I could understand it correctly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234819/publishing-a-message-in-an-interrupt/) by [Loreno](https://answers.ros.org/users/26934/loreno/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The closest thing to an "interrupt" in ROS is that ROS uses callbacks that get called when particular ROS events happen. For example, when creating a subscriber you provide a callback function that executes every time a message on a particular topic is received. You could easily publish a topic in a subscriber callback. There are also callbacks for service providers (which could also contain a publish command).

One thing you may be interested in is a Timer ([Python](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time#Timer) and [CPP](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Timers)). These allow you to specify a callback and a time period (as a `ros::Duration`). The callback will then be executed at the frequency specified by the time period. You can, of course, publish messages in that timer callback as well.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0